# Как с помощью библиотеки apscheduler реализовать вызов функции с заданной периодичностью и началом отчета кратному периодичности?

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

Как в python с помощью библиотеки apscheduler настроить вызов функции foo с периодичностью 2 минуты и началом отчета кратному периодичности? Ниже приведен рабочий код, для приведенного примера отсчет идет каждые 2 минуты с момента запуска. То есть если на момент запуска время было 18:37:00, то следующий запуск будет 18:39:00, 18:41:00 и т.д., а требуется чтобы было 18:38:00, 18:40:00, 18:42:00 и т.д.

```
import schedule
from datetime import datetime


import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


async def foo():
    print(f'{datetime.now()} Foo')


async def main():

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(foo, "interval", seconds=10,
                      start_date='2022-05-14 17:25:00')
    scheduler.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: вопрос непонятен или неверен даже. "пеоридичностью 2 минуты" + "со времени 00:00:00" + "на момент запуска время было 18:37:00", то запуск в "18:39:00" полностью удовлетворяет условию, а вы хотите 18:38:00 непонятно почему.

Comment: Такое требование задачи. То есть если у меня будет задана периодичность 10 минут, мне нужно чтобы функция запускалась в 00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50  минут каждого часа, а не начинала отсчет 10 минут с момента запуска программы.

Comment: Ясно, "отсчет начинался всегда со времени 00:00:00" относится не к вызову, а к моменту начала периодичности.

Comment: Я бы `time` и `datetime` использовал. Определял текущее время и потом что-то типа `if dt.minute%2` + `time.sleep`

Comment: тогда мне нужно было запускать все джобы - каждую 1 минут, а внутри отслеживать необходимый период. не совсем удобное и красивое решение.  Сейчас пробую - AsyncIOScheduler и посмотрю какие у него возможности

Comment: я потому в коммент его и внес, а не в ответ, как хотел изначально. Да, пробуйте AsyncIOScheduler, напишите, если поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно в start_date указать любую дату из прошлого, а время = 00:00:00. В этом случае запуск функции будет начинаться во время кратному заданному интервалу.

```
import schedule
from datetime import datetime


import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


async def foo():
    print(f'{datetime.now()} Foo')


async def main():

    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(foo, "interval", seconds=10,
                      start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00')
    scheduler.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```